# google maps & fusion tables API with multiple layers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

i'm trying to show a transit route map that allows the user to click on checkboxes to filter by direction. i keep getting the "data may still be loading.." error that does not seem to resolve on refresh/zooming/etc.

there are two layers (one with routes and the other with stops) that reference two google fusion tables. the same directional filter feeds into the queries for both tables (i.e., NB filters for both stop and route)

i've tried showing only one layer (by commenting out the other) and both seem to work fine on their own. also, the stops data table has about 600 entries, so i don't think this is a limit issue?

this is the code in the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

    // Change these variables for each route
    var routeNumber = '257';                // Route number as string
    var mapLatitude = 37.9985;              // Center of map latitude
    var mapLongitude = -122.5372;           // Center of map longitude
    var zoomLevel = 13;                     // Map zoom level

    // Map display options
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapLatitude, mapLongitude),
      zoom: zoomLevel,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // Create map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    // Create fusion table layers
    var stopLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();
    var routeLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();
    filterMap(routeLayer, stopLayer, map, routeNumber);

    // Call filter function on click action
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('NB'),
        'click', function() {
            filterMap(routeLayer, stopLayer, map, routeNumber);

    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('SB'),
        'click', function() {
            filterMap(routeLayer, stopLayer, map, routeNumber);
    });

    // Filter function to create query
    function filterMap(routeLayer, stopLayer, map, routeNumber) {
        var where = generateWhere();    

        if (where) {
            if (!routeLayer.getMap()) {
                routeLayer.setMap(map);
            }
            if (!stopLayer.getMap()) {
                stopLayer.setMap(map);
            }

            routeLayer.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: 'Location',
                    from: '1RG-EcymqePVLwa-7lmmkQVdn0RCW4fjQJFouTsc',
                    where: "'Route Number' LIKE " + routeNumber + " AND " + where
                }
            });

            stopLayer.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: 'latitude',
                    from: '1GTjjCaqkYTM3IDhrt2x8pWO73wCu7KTM1bbEcG8',
                    where: "'Marin Transit Routes' LIKE '%" + routeNumber + "%' AND " + where
                }
            });

        } else {
            stopLayer.setMap(null);
        }
    }

    // Generates string of checked options to feed into query
    function generateWhere() {
        var filter = [];
        var directions = document.getElementsByName('direction');
        for (var i = 0, direction; direction = directions[i]; i++) {
            if (direction.checked) {
                var directionName = direction.value.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
                filter.push("'" + directionName + "'");
            }
        }
        var where = '';
        if (filter.length) {
            where = "'Direction' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
        }
        return where;
    }

}
</script>
```

this is the code in the `<body>`

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="direction" id="NB" value="NB" /><label>NB</label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="direction" id="SB" value="SB" /><label>SB</label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

ok, so i tried switching the layers back around the next day and it worked! but then after making some edits to the code and/or fusion table data, i was having a similar issue with some stops/styling not rendering. after about an hour or so, the styling started showing for some of the points.. (stops should all be either large or small *green* icons)

[image: map screenshot]

maybe it's an issue with refreshing the tiles? as the correctly displayed stops look like they're all within one map tile and it changes as i zoom. has anyone encountered this? and if so, is there some way to force a refresh or prevent this from happening?

code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mobilemelody/u9vhD/4/

Comment: I put your code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/tzswC/. So what exactly does not work? I can't reproduce the error. Is it possible that you added styling rules to both of the layers? Because FT only allows one layer to have styles applied.

Comment: thanks for your response. when i tested that link, i am still getting the error. also, i have not added any styling yet. however, i think i figured it out (or at least a work-around). for some reason, when i switched the order of the layers it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i think i figured out a work-around for now. for some reason, when i switch the order of the layers, it works.

this is the updated section of the script

```
// Filter function to create query
    function filterMap(routeLayer, stopLayer, map, routeNumber) {
        var where = generateWhere();

        if (where) {
            if (!stopLayer.getMap()) {
                stopLayer.setMap(map);
            }
            if (!routeLayer.getMap()) {
                routeLayer.setMap(map);
            }

            stopLayer.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: 'latitude',
                    from: '1GTjjCaqkYTM3IDhrt2x8pWO73wCu7KTM1bbEcG8',
                    where: "'Marin Transit Routes' LIKE '%" + routeNumber + "%' AND " + where
                }
            });

            routeLayer.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: 'Location',
                    from: '1RG-EcymqePVLwa-7lmmkQVdn0RCW4fjQJFouTsc',
                    where: "'Route Number' LIKE " + routeNumber + " AND " + where
                },
                suppressInfoWindows: true
            });

        } else {
            stopLayer.setMap(null);
            routeLayer.setMap(null);
        }
    }
```

however, when ordered in this way, the route lines end up being on top of the stops, making it a little tricky to click on the stops and get the info window to pop-up.. if anyone has a better solution, it'd be much appreciated